# Flutter Firestore chat not working, display gives errors

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been implementing chat for Flutter through Firestore, and am unable to display the main page itself and the chat groups. The following is the method to get the user groups:

```
getUserGroups() async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(uid).snapshots();
  }
```

This is the method to display the groups:

```
_getUserAuthAndJoinedGroups() async {
    _username = (await storage.read(key: 'username')).toString();
    if (mounted) setState(() {});
    DatabaseService(_username).getUserGroups().then((snapshots) {
      // print(snapshots);
      setState(() {
        _groups = snapshots;
      });
    });
  }

Widget groupsList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _groups,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var data = snapshot.data;
          if (data['groups'] != null) {
            // print(snapshot.data['groups'].length);
            if (snapshot.data['groups'].length != 0) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data['groups'].length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    int reqIndex = snapshot.data['groups'].length - index - 1;
                    return GroupTile(
                        snapshot.data['fullName'],
                        _destructureId(snapshot.data['groups'][reqIndex]),
                        _destructureName(snapshot.data['groups'][reqIndex]));
                  });
            } else {
              return noGroupWidget();
            }
          } else {
            return noGroupWidget();
          }
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

For the above code snippet, data['groups'] gives me the error:

> Object? data
> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Lastly, this declaration gives me an error: Non-nullable instance field '_groups' must be initialized.

```
Stream _groups;
```

I have used the 'late' modifier, '?' and '!', but it isn't resolved.

Answer (score 1):

How about you change all `snapshot.data['groups']` after `var data = snapshot.data;` into `data['groups']`?

Because you are wrapping with condition `if (data['groups'] != null)`, it should not return message that `data['groups']` might be null after that condition, if all `snapshot.data['groups']` after `var data = snapshot.data;` into `data['groups']`.

AFTER

```dart
if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var data = snapshot.data;
          if (data['groups'] != null) {
            // print(snapshot.data['groups'].length);
            if (data['groups'].length != 0) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data['groups'].length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    int reqIndex = data['groups'].length - index - 1;
                    return GroupTile(
                        snapshot.data['fullName'],
                        _destructureId(data['groups'][reqIndex]),
                        _destructureName(data['groups'][reqIndex]));
                  });
            } else {
              return noGroupWidget();
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to a Flutter update, there is no need to use .data().